Bottom Sheet Above Tab Bar like Find My app
How would you make the .sheet presented above the tab bar wihtout covering it in SwiftUi? I've seen a somewhat solution but not one in SwiftUi.

So far anything I try just places the sheet overlaying the tab bar
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showSheet = true

    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            HomeView(showSheet: $showSheet)
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Home", systemImage: "house")
                }
            Text("Second Tab")
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Second", systemImage: "2.circle")
                }
        }
    }
}

struct HomeView: View {
    @Binding var showSheet: Bool

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Show TabView Sheet") {
                showSheet.toggle()
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
                SheetContent()
                    .presentationDetents([.medium, .large])
                    .interactiveDismissDisabled()
                    .presentationBackgroundInteraction(.enabled(upThrough: .large))
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SheetContent: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("First Tab Content")
            Text("More Content in the Sheet")
            // Add more content here as needed
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}



While both methods below from Benzy Neez and myself are valid, you may still run into issues when trying to edit the content on the actual overlay size the height is constantly resizing. Best is to use this and follow my detailed explanation in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78686848/16810909


In your example, the sheet cannot be dismissed interactively, but background interaction has been enabled. So I would suggest, an overlay could be used to replace the sheet:
// ContentView

HomeView(showSheet: $showSheet)
    .tabItem {
        Label("Home", systemImage: "house")
    }
    .toolbarBackground(.visible, for: .tabBar)
    .toolbarBackground(.background, for: .tabBar)

struct HomeView: View {
    @Binding var showSheet: Bool

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Show TabView Sheet") {
                showSheet.toggle()
            }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
            if showSheet {
                SheetContent()
                    .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
            }
        }
        .animation(.easeInOut, value: showSheet)
    }
}

struct SheetContent: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("First Tab Content")
            Text("More Content in the Sheet")
            // Add more content here as needed
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 200)
        .background {
            UnevenRoundedRectangle(cornerRadii: .init(topLeading: 20, topTrailing: 20))
                .fill(.yellow)
        }
    }
}



EDIT You were asking in a comment if it would be possible to resize the overlay. You would need to implement this yourself using a drag gesture. Perhaps something like this:
struct SheetContent: View {
    let minHeight: CGFloat = 200
    let maxHeight: CGFloat = 450
    @State private var extraHeight = CGFloat.zero
    @State private var dragHeight = CGFloat.zero

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("First Tab Content")
            Text("More Content in the Sheet")
            // Add more content here as needed
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: minHeight + extraHeight)
        .offset(y: -dragHeight / 2)
        .background {
            UnevenRoundedRectangle(cornerRadii: .init(topLeading: 20, topTrailing: 20))
                .padding(.bottom, -300)
                .foregroundStyle(.yellow)
                .offset(y: -dragHeight)
        }
        .overlay(alignment: .top) {
            Capsule()
                .frame(width: 36, height: 5)
                .foregroundStyle(.secondary)
                .padding(5)
                .offset(y: -dragHeight)
                .gesture(
                    DragGesture()
                        .onChanged { val in
                            let dy = -val.translation.height
                            let minDragHeight = minHeight - (minHeight + extraHeight)
                            let maxDragHeight = maxHeight - (minHeight + extraHeight)
                            dragHeight = min(max(dy, minDragHeight), maxDragHeight)
                        }
                        .onEnded { val in
                            extraHeight = extraHeight + dragHeight
                            dragHeight = 0
                        }
                )
        }
    }
}



Is there a way to make this overlay behave like a sheet though? (Presentation detents that allow it to be resized to .medium and .large)

Answer updated to show how resizing could be implemented using a drag gesture

One issue I'm still having now is the height of the overlay when changing tabs. I'm trying to make it so the tab changes the content in the overlay. But when doing that, the height of the current postion of the overlay does not update to the second tab. I can't paste all the code in a comment: https://github.com/sheehanmunim/tabbarandbottom/blob/main/tabbarandbottom/ContentView.swift

@SheehanMunim Pleased to hear you're making progress, thanks for accepting the answer. Re. the height of the overlay when changing tabs - if you want the overlay to persist between tab changes then it sounds like it needs to be attached to the parent view instead of to the child views. Unfortunately, this doesn't work when the parent view is a TabView. However, it would work with a ZStack + custom tab bar, which is how my answer started out. Let me know if you would like me to revert the earlier part of my answer (alternatively, you can find it in the history).

Based On Benzy Neez's answer, I also implemented smother animation and snapping points to make it look like a sheet. (Huge thanks to Benzy Neez)
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showSheet = true

    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            HomeView(showSheet: $showSheet)
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Home", systemImage: "house")
                }
                .toolbarBackground(.visible, for: .tabBar)
                .toolbarBackground(.background, for: .tabBar)
            Text("Second Tab")
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Second", systemImage: "2.circle")
                }
        }
    }
}

struct HomeView: View {
    @Binding var showSheet: Bool
    

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Show TabView Sheet") {
                showSheet.toggle()
            }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
            if showSheet {
                SheetContent()
                    .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
            }
        }
        .animation(.easeInOut, value: showSheet)
    }
}

struct SheetContent: View {
    let minHeight: CGFloat = 100
    let snapHeight: CGFloat = 150
    let midHeight: CGFloat = 400
    let maxHeight: CGFloat = 700
    @State private var extraHeight = CGFloat.zero
    @State private var dragHeight = CGFloat.zero

    init() {
        _extraHeight = State(initialValue: snapHeight - minHeight)
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("First Tab Content")
            Text("More Content in the Sheet")
            
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: minHeight + extraHeight)
        .offset(y: -dragHeight / 2)
        .background {
            UnevenRoundedRectangle(cornerRadii: .init(topLeading: 20, topTrailing: 20))
                .padding(.bottom, -300)
                .foregroundStyle(.yellow)
                .offset(y: -dragHeight)
        }
        .overlay(alignment: .top) {
            Capsule()
                .frame(width: 36, height: 5)
                .foregroundStyle(.secondary)
                .padding(5)
                .offset(y: -dragHeight)
        }
        .animation(.easeInOut, value: extraHeight)
        .animation(.easeInOut, value: dragHeight)
        .gesture(
            DragGesture()
                .onChanged { val in
                    let dy = -val.translation.height
                    let minDragHeight = minHeight - (minHeight + extraHeight)
                    let maxDragHeight = maxHeight - (minHeight + extraHeight)
                    dragHeight = min(max(dy, minDragHeight), maxDragHeight)
                }
                .onEnded { _ in
                    let snapPoints: [CGFloat] = [snapHeight, midHeight, maxHeight]
                    let currentHeight = minHeight + extraHeight + dragHeight
                    let closestSnapPoint = snapPoints.min(by: { abs($0 - currentHeight) < abs($1 - currentHeight) }) ?? snapHeight
                    withAnimation(.easeInOut) {
                        extraHeight = closestSnapPoint - minHeight
                        dragHeight = 0
                    }
                }
        )
    }
}



#Preview {
    ContentView()
}



